# American equivalent of "on spec"

Tags: phrase-request, american-english

The Merriam-Webster Advanced Learner's Dictionary labels "on spec" British. I'm wondering what its American counterpart is.

Its definition is "without being sure of success but with the hope of success."

> He wrote to the company **on spec**, hoping for a job.

Comment: The M-W definition I found gives the definition _without having a definite buyer or customer but with the hope or expectation of finding one when work is completed_ - it's only the definition you quote (which seems very similar to me) which is labelled British.

Comment: The crossword clue 'Work on spec (9 letters)' had the answer 'freelance' in _USA Today_ in 2022, and it's in Merriam-Webster and American Heritage Dictionary not labelled 'British'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "On spec" is used in AE in limited contexts such as you decribed, but not in those the OP sentence describes.

Comment: If you are are a freelancer (working on spec), you are not sure of success (in getting a living) but hopeful of it. This is unlike having a permanent job or an employment contract. That is exactly the meaning of the dictionary definition.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The usage you decribed is related to production, and that's the only occassion where "on spec" is used in AE. See here: https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/10kvvvy/comment/j5t70mo/?context=3

Comment: This comment by an AE speaker: "It's used in America but only in specific contexts. In Hollywood, a screenwriter can either be hired to write a script for a specific movie that's already being produced, or they can write a script on their own and try to sell it to a production studio. The latter is called writing "on spec," or just a "spec script."

I guess it's just used more widely in British English though. **You'd certainly never hear your example sentence in American English.**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree that the example sentence:

> He wrote to the company on spec, hoping for a job.

would not be usual in US English. In my experience one does not use "on spec" to refer to seeking a job. The expressions "cold call", "applied cold", or "took a chance" might be used for applying for a job when none had been advertised.

The term "*freelancing*" generally means doing work on a job-by-job basis, without a long term employment relationship. It may be equated with "independent contractor". But a freelancer would not usually be said to do work "*on spec*". That would mean doing work with no agreement that it would be paid for, merely in hopes of obtaining payment.

The term  "*on spec*" is frequently used in US English to mean creating something, such as  a house, an artwork, a piece of software, or some other item, in hopes of selling it, but without any order, and usually without even any specific buyer in mind. "Spec" is short for "speculation", because the maker speculates that a buyer will be found, but is not assured of this. In that sense the term is in common use in AmE. But I don't recall ever having heard it in connection with a job application.

Comment: Agreed this seems odd for a job application but it is particularly common usage in the home building arena. If it _were_ used about a job application I would say that it would need to be limited to cases where the potential employer hasn't even advertised an open position.